# Is there a way to offset tableview animations so that they don't show all at once?

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to figure out how to apply an animation to cells of a tableview without the need of an external array. I want the animation to happen only once as the user scrolls down, but reset when the user swipes down to reload the data. I've opted with a boolean variable animatedAlready in the custom cell class definition--and it works, but the animations are being registered so quickly and that the animations don't appear consistently. Also, I'm struggling to find a way to reset the value of animatedAlready in each cell when the tableview is refreshed...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //If transactionPage is set to -1, it's because we've reached the end of the transactions
    if transactionPage != -1 && indexPath.row == (tableData.rows(inSection: indexPath.section).count) - 1 {
        loadMoreTransactions()
    }

    if let cell = cell as? CustomCell, !cell.animatedAlready {
        cell.alpha = 0
        cell.animatedAlready = true

        //Slide from bottom
        let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 200, 0)

        cell.layer.transform = transform

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.alpha = 1
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        })
    }
}
```

and my current attempt to reload the animation:

```
    @objc func reloadBalanceAndTransactions() {
        refreshControl.beginRefreshing()

        tableView.reloadWithAnimation()

        //Reset
        transactionPage = 0
        callbackCount = 2

        loadBalance()
        loadMoreTransactions()
    }
```

the extension (I totally know that this is wrong, just couldn't think of anything else):

```
func reloadWithAnimation() {
        self.reloadData()
        let tableViewHeight = self.bounds.size.height
        let cells = self.visibleCells
        var delayCounter = 0
        for cell in cells {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: tableViewHeight)
        }
        for cell in cells {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.6, delay: 0.08 * Double(delayCounter),usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }, completion: nil)
            delayCounter += 1
        }
    }

    func scrollToTop(animated: Bool = false) {
        self.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0), at: .top, animated: animated)
    }
```

Comment: note .. https://medium.com/liveop-x-team/accelerating-h264-decoding-on-ios-with-ffmpeg-and-videotoolbox-1f000cb6c549  .. the answers there are not erally very good but notice the comment by me ..

Answer (score 2):

It's incredibly hard to sync animes in table cells.

The secret is you need a signaling system - *which runs on its own and independently of everything else in the app* - and which keeps track of time.

That signaling system singleton - each cell should connect to it and animate based on that.  (Or, depending on your style, the signaling system connects to the cells and tells them what to do.)